For loop running only for first element
I'm using the below code to check if the input value match with any value of google sheet column.
The logger returns an array of all phone numbers in the specified column, but the for loop works only for the first phone number in the array. And also I would be grateful if you guide how to get the same results using if (allNumbers.flat().indexOf(newPhone) != -1) and which way is better.
function phoneSearch(newPhone) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
    var allNumbers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getDisplayValues();
    Logger.log(allNumbers.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
      if (allNumbers[i][0] == newPhone) {
        var result = "not available"
      } else {
        var result = "available"
      };
      return result;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}


you return result; - which ends the loop - you should format your code, it'll be easy to spot then

Because from the client side I'm using onsuccess handler:
function onSuccess(result) { if (result == "not available") { Do something } else { Do something } }
so I have to return the result of the for loop in the server side to complete the action in the client side. Thanks @Jaromanda X

yes, but your code always returns a value from the for loop, therefore, you're not looping more than once - ever - that's what return does, it returns a value from a function

Yes I realized the problem but I can't figure out another way to get what I want, I tried to flatten the array and use index of but also no luck. Any ideas I would be so grateful

Your function always returns from the first iteration of the loop. You should return only if the number is taken, and if it isn't, continue checking the other numbers.
function phoneSearch(newPhone){
    try {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
        var allNumbers = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow() -1,1).getDisplayValues();
        Logger.log(allNumbers.length);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (allNumbers[i][0] == newPhone) {
                return "not available"
            }
         }
        
         // If "not available" wasn't returned from the loop, the number is avialable
         return "available";
    } catch(e) {
         // Probably need some more robust treatment here
    }
}


Others on this page have explained that your loop returns after one iteration
Array.flat is a useful way to do what you want.
It is as simple as
function phoneSearch(newPhone) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
    var allNumbers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getDisplayValues();
    return allNumbers.flat().includes(newNumber) ? 'not available' : 'available';
  } catch (e) {}
}

If you are worried about the execution time, you really should cache the values returned from the sheet
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let allNumbers = []; 
  try { // store the list once
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
    allNumbers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getDisplayValues();
    allNumbers = allNumbers.flat();
  } catch (e) {}

  const numberAvailable = (newPhone) => !allNumbers.includes(newNumber);

  const addNumber = (newPhone) {
    if (numberAvailable(newPhone)) {
      allNumbers.push(newPhone); // update the list used by testing availability
      // write allNumbers to sheet or add newNumber
    } else {
      console.log('Number not available'); // handle existing number
    }
  };
});


Thanks a lot. Would you think flatten the array is better than looping in this case, from execution time point of view?

Depends on the size. See update
